# Using De Moivre's theorem . $(1+i)^{100}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Find all the values of  $(1+i)^{100}   $

i used De Moivre's theorem to tackle this problem. 
$$(1+i)=\sqrt{2}(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4)) $$ 
using the theorem, 
$$ (1+i)^{100}=\sqrt{2}(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4))^{100}$$
after some calculations, 
$$=2^{50}(\cos(8n+1)25\pi+i\sin(8n+1)25\pi)$$
 putting $n=0,1,2,\ldots,99$,we get the  required values. 
My solution is correct ?

Comment: I think it should be just a complex number. Like if you put n = 1 into the formula then you get for the real part 2^50*cos(225pi) which is just 2^50*cos(pi) and cos(pi) is -1.

Comment: How do you mean find all the values of $(1+i)^{100}$?

Comment: I think op is confusing roots and integer powers.

Comment: you want to find all the values ? Does that expression has more than one value?

Comment: i did not come up with the question. This was a question in a test exam. i solved it like this.

Comment: Did you mean $(1+i)^{ \frac{1}{100}}$

Comment: No, i did not. i solved problems like those with De moivre's. But this kind of problems should also be solved by that theorem. There is no restrictions.right ?

Comment: @MathLover ,$n$ came from the theorem.

Comment: http://www.mathwords.com/d/demoivres_thm.htm two problems here, one with integer power and one with root

Comment: My solution is correct. Just did not notice they gave same solutions. 
Thank you too @randomgirl.

Comment: I would say if you wrote this on the exam there is fat chance that you aren't getting full points or even any points at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$2^{50}(\cos(8n+1)25\pi+i\sin(8n+1)25\pi)=2^{50}(\cos 25\pi+i\sin25\pi)$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

There is only one solution. Your $100$ solutions can be proven to be the same complex number using the property that sines and cosines are function with period $2\pi$.

If we square a complex number, we just get a single complex number rather than $2$.

If you are taking a square root, then perhaps you can find two solutions.

Edit:

\begin{align}2^{50}(\cos(8n+1)25\pi+i\sin(8n+1)25\pi)&=2^{50}(\cos 25\pi+i\sin25\pi)\\&= 2^{50}(\cos \pi+i\sin\pi)\\
&= -2^{50}\end{align}

Comment: so , $2^{50}$ and$-2^{50}$ ?

Comment: $2^{50}=(-2)^{50}$ and $2^{50} \neq -2^{50}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, my solution is correct. Even though i did not notice that they give the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

We have $(1+i)^{100} = (2i)^{50} = (-4)^{25} = - 2^{50} = -1125899906842624.$